# How to recover data from a table, and store that into list?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, data-recovery

How can I get **ALL** the data from a table of my DB (mySQL) using hibernate, and store the output into List of Objects?

I'll use this List, to populate a JTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Foo");
List foos = q.list();
```

Where `Foo` is an entity mapped on your table. But maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

If you use findAll(), which should be a part of the GenericDAO, it returns everything as a List.